# Blue border due to focus on ckedtior, how to remove it

Tags: php, css, ckeditor

I'm using the Version 4.6.2 of Ckeditor, and i'm actually having some troubles with it because on chrome when i select an element in the textarea, like the buttons and everything there is a blue border that go around all the ckeditor and i wanted to remove it, I search but i found some solutions for the previous version I think but not for this one. Does anyone know how to remove that blue border due to focus ? Thanks.

Comment: That's the `outline`. You can remove it by doing `outline: none;` but you're taking out a feature that is meant for accessibility.

Comment: I don't know what is it for and accessibility like how it helps ? But anyway in ckeditor i just have to put outline: none; but where ? And if it's important i can only modify it maybe ?

Comment: Accessibility tackles an important aspect of a website - ease of use for the general user and most importantly for those users who have physical disabilities and have a different set of requirements when browsing web pages. Also I tried installing CKEditor and the widget didn't have any outlines with it when it gained the focus. Try to learn how to debug by using your web developer tools.

Comment: Thanks for the info it's good to know. Here i just want to delete it from a textarea because there is a border I don't want for the moment. Maybe after I will change it and instead of a gradient of blue I'll put a simple border, but for me it's easier to remove it now. I will try to reinstall it then maybe I did something wrong :/ I already know how to debug with my webrowser that's not the problem here, because there is so many div class to modify it's impossible.. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you update your question and give us some screenshots? Also inspect the element that shows the blue border and copy the relevant styles applied to it in your question as well.

Comment: So my question is how to remove the blue border appearing when I click on my textarea (ckeditor) Screenshot : http://nsa37.casimages.com/img/2017/03/24/170324091341824059.png. For the styles applied to it, there are so many <div class=""> because ckeditor is the plugin I put and he do the work for me so i can't show all of them but the main textarea have : 
`span.cke_skin_kama {
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}`

Comment: A quick solution is to use `*:focus { outline: none; }` but like I said - that's not a good practice as outlines are there for a reason and that this solution will remove all outlines from your page not just from CKEditor. You'll have to learn how to hunt these things down yourself as we can't inspect the page unless you provide a live link.

Comment: Yeah that's not a solution because as you said it's useful and I want to disable it to after transform it because the gradient is 'eww' ^^ I already did bu for each class there is a button and each button when you click on it the outline appear :/ So I search all the classes to put it away/transform it in a border but i can't. That's why I'm searching someone good at Ckeditor to tell me if there is a way to do it the config of ckeditor.. I can provide you a link but not here :/ Have you an email adress ?

Comment: I believe you have a custom skin applied which might be applying that `outline` as your screenshot looks different from this [CKEditor v.4.6.2 Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy6ptnmj/21/). If you have a different installation from the *Standard* plugin installation it would help to let us know.

Comment: Yes I have the Customize one but i don't know it can change from a package to another. I test the basic one :)

Comment: If you can't provide a live link here try to recreate the widget in a Fiddle or something so we can inspect what is causing the problem.

Comment: Ok, so with the standard one i don't have the outline ^^ Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

You could alter .ck-focused class.

```css
.ck-focused { 
  border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a css class with `outline: none` property, for example, class

`no-outline{
    outline: none;
}`

And then add it to elements you want to remove the blue border from. Ex.
`<button class="no-outline">Button with no outline</button>`